# Echarts.js tooltip not showing with formatter function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, echarts

Echarts.js on Angular 10 and these are my toltip options :

```
  tooltip: {
    show: true,
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'line',
      lineStyle: {
        color: eTheme.tooltipLineColor,
        width: eTheme.tooltipLineWidth,
      },
    },
    textStyle: {
      color: eTheme.tooltipTextColor,
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: eTheme.tooltipFontWeight,
    },
    position: 'top',
    backgroundColor: eTheme.tooltipBg,
    borderColor: eTheme.tooltipBorderColor,
    borderWidth: 1,
    extraCssText: eTheme.tooltipExtraCss,
    formatter : (params) => {
      return Math.round(parseInt(params[0].value, 10));
    },
  },
```

The problems is that with formatter my tooltip is not showing , when i delete formatter - everything is fine and tooltip is showing again.

What is wrong with formatter ?

Comment: Did you fix it?